# App is showing up in iTunes file sharing but documents are not (they have previously)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, itunes, file-sharing, nsdocumentdirectory

I've enabled file sharing in my app and it works as far as when I go to file sharing in iTunes the app icon shows up. However none of the documents do.
This is especially strange due to the fact that at one point they did and now suddenly they don't. The file is saved in to the documents directory and it saves in to my app and can be loaded no problem within the app itself.

My code to save to documents is as follows:

```
NSArray * pathsFree = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * freeDocumentsDirectory = [pathsFree objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *freeHipHopFilePath = [freeDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FreeHipHopMixerOutput.m4a"];
```

I have the bundle display name set to `${PRODUCT_NAME}` but from what i've seen in the more recent questions this is not even a necessity any more to get file sharing to work.

I'm using an iphone 5c running iOS 10.3.2 and the version of itunes is 12.6.1 and finally the version of xcode is 8.3.3. Is a combination of these causing some sort of problem?

I'm at a complete loss as it doesn't seem like anyone else has encountered this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not the only one! I used this for an app where the user can transfer documents with iTunes File Sharing. Suddenly, although the icons appear in the Sharing section, none of the apps I have will now allow the files to be shown. Also, adding files from iTunes does not work either. There is no error message in iTunes, but the files do not appear and the app can't access them either! Nobody seems to care, though, especially not Apple :-(

Comment: Well, this is a coincidence.. Just updated macOS Sierra to 10.12.6 (16G29) and suddenly, iTunes File Sharing is working again!